# Click a button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, onclick

I have the following code:

```
<a class="sectionname" href="#" onclick="expandAll();return false;">Expand all</a>
```

When I click on expand all, the whole page loads. How can I do it using WebDriver for Python?

Comment: Post your Python-script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you can use the `find_element_by_link_text` and invoke `click()` method as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Expand all").click()
```

You can get more granualar with `find_element_by_xpath` as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='sectionname' and contains(.,'Expand all')]").click()
```

---

### Update

As you still don't see the expansion you can try the *Javascript* way as follows :

```
myElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='sectionname' and contains(.,'Expand all')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", myElement)
```

Comment: The code runs without error, but still no action on the page.

Comment: I am sure our line of code is perfect, what I suspect is the _onclick_ event as `"expandAll();return false;"` which doesn't makes any sense to me. Are you able to do it _Manually_? How much time does the page takes to change?

Comment: Yes I am able to do it manually. and only a few milliseconds. As the page is already loaded, but all the data is collapsed.

Comment: Yes, the updated answer works.Could you please explain your solution?

Comment: Initially we tried to click on the `WebElement` through `link_text` and then `xpath` in which we didn't succeed. So finally we took help of `JavascriptExecutor` which interacts the _WebElement_ directly and we were successful. Let me know if you have any further queries.