# How to click an image given an Xpath in Selinum with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

So I have the HTML code: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6M8W.png)

How do I click this button? What is the Xpath for this one?

Comment: The answer is available easily even on Google also. Please consider researching over a topic and then ask here on stack overflow...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click a button using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273604/click-a-button-using-selenium-and-python)

Answer (score 1):

The xPath to that particular image is

```
/html/body/img
```

To click it

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/img")).click()
```

Comment: This is not the correct XPATH. The OP is referring to the button in the image

Answer (score 0):

For xpath you need to have a path from top level upto this button.
Would look something like `html\body\div\button` [ just an example ].

You will have to check the whole page to navigate to that button using xpath.

Another better way could be using find element by `class="auth-button positive"` and then `click()` it